# How To Make An Actor Touchable LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx, actor

I'm having some problems trying to make my Actors touchable. Here is the code that I'm using. The **first class is where I create the buttons**.

```java
import personajes.Jugador;

public class Botones extends Actor {
    protected Texture texture;
    protected Sprite sprite;
    protected SpriteBatch batch;
    protected ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    public Botones(Jugador j) {
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        this.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Mapas/upButtonFinal.png"));
        this.sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setBounds(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 18.9666f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 6.4f, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 11, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 11);

    }
    public static class BotonAbajo extends Botones {
        public BotonAbajo(Jugador j){
            super(j);
            shapeRenderer=new ShapeRenderer();
            texture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Mapas/downButtonFinal.png"));
            this.sprite=new Sprite(texture);
            sprite.setBounds(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/18.9625f,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/54,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/11,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/11);

        }
    }

    public static class BotonDerecha extends Botones {
        public BotonDerecha(Jugador j){
            super(j);
            shapeRenderer=new ShapeRenderer();
            texture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Mapas/rightButton.png"));
            this.sprite=new Sprite(texture);
            sprite.setBounds(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/8.9666f,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/21,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/12,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/13);

        }
    }

    public static class BotonIzquierda extends Botones {
        public BotonIzquierda(Jugador j){
            super(j);
            shapeRenderer=new ShapeRenderer();
            texture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Mapas/leftButton.png"));
            this.sprite=new Sprite(texture);
            sprite.setBounds(0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/23,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/11,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/11);
        }
    }
    public void dibujarConHitbox(){
        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.box(sprite.getX(),sprite.getY(),0,sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight(),20);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        shapeRenderer.end();
    }


}
```

**The second class is where I try to implement it. This class is a map where I try to implement a touchable actor. It is supposed to print "Hola", if I click the actor. It will later do something else, but for now I'm just trying to print that. Anyways, it seems like nothing is detected, and I don't know why.** I already tried to: **This.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled)** in Botones, but it doesn't work either.

```java
public class Mapa2 extends BaseScreen {
    private Juego juego;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private EntradaCasaMapa2 ecm;
    private SalidaMapa2 sm;


    public Mapa2(Juego g){
        super(g);
        this.juego=g;
        shapeRenderer=new ShapeRenderer();

         map = new TmxMapLoader().load("Mapas/MapaInicialFinal.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map,unitScale);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.translate(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
        camera.update();
         properties = map.getProperties();
        tileWidth = properties.get("tilewidth", Integer.class);
        tileHeight = properties.get("tileheight", Integer.class);
        mapWidthInTiles = properties.get("width", Integer.class);
        mapHeightInTiles = properties.get("height", Integer.class);
        mapWidthInPixels = mapWidthInTiles * tileWidth;
        mapHeightInPixels = mapHeightInTiles * tileHeight;
        batch=new SpriteBatch();
        //Crear variable para posicionPersonajeX e Y, para que segun desde que mapa entre, se origine el jugador en un lado u otro.
        jugador=new Jugador(map,camera,480,500,mapWidthInPixels/20 ,mapHeightInPixels/20 );
        System.out.println(mapWidthInTiles);//El sout de mapWidthInTiles y Heigh da la altura y anchura del mapa, el de Gdx da el viewportWidth y Heigth
        System.out.println(mapHeightInTiles);
        //MUY IMPORTANTE, DURANTE LA FASE DE ORDENADOR, EL PERSONAJE ESTARÁ EN 280,100,/20,/20, PERO EN MOVIL ESTARÁ EN 1080,150,/10,/5

        WIDTH = ((TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0)).getWidth(); //Obtenemos desde el mapa el número de tiles de ancho de la 1º Capa
        HEIGHT = ((TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0)).getHeight(); //Obtenemos desde el mapa el número de tiles de alto de la 1º Capa
        System.out.println(WIDTH);
        System.out.println(HEIGHT);
        camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        camera.position.x=WIDTH/2;
        camera.position.y=HEIGHT/2;
        camera.position.set(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2,1);

        MapLayers mapLayers = map.getLayers();
        terrainLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer) mapLayers.get("Suelo");
        terrainLayer2 = (TiledMapTileLayer) mapLayers.get("Cosas");

        colisiones=new Colisiones();
        colisiones.checkCollision(map,jugador);

        InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
        multiplexer.addProcessor(new TecladoJugador(jugador));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);

        pantalla=new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(pantalla);
        pantalla.setDebugAll(true);
        pantalla.addActor(jugador);
        botonArriba=new Botones(jugador);
        botonAbajo=new Botones.BotonAbajo(jugador);
        botonIzquierda=new Botones.BotonIzquierda(jugador);
        botonDerecha=new Botones.BotonDerecha(jugador);
        ecm=new EntradaCasaMapa2();
        sm=new SalidaMapa2();

        pantalla.addActor(botonArriba);
        botonArriba.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        pantalla.addActor(botonAbajo);
        pantalla.addActor(botonIzquierda);
        pantalla.addActor(botonDerecha);
        pantalla.addActor(ecm);
        pantalla.addActor(sm);



        botonArriba.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                System.out.println("Hola");
            }
        });



        for(int b=0;b<colisiones.getActores().length-1;b++){
            pantalla.addActor(colisiones.getActores()[b]);
            colisiones.getActores()[b].setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
        System.out.println(colisiones.getActores().length);

    }




    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        super.render(delta);

        renderer.getBatch().begin();
        renderer.renderTileLayer(terrainLayer);
        renderer.getBatch().end();
        batch.begin();
        jugador.dibujarConHitbox(batch);
       // upImg.draw(batch,delta);
        batch.end();
        renderer.getBatch().begin();
        renderer.renderTileLayer(terrainLayer2);
        renderer.getBatch().end();
        ecm.dibujar();
        sm.dibujar();
        botonArriba.dibujarConHitbox();
        botonAbajo.dibujarConHitbox();
        botonIzquierda.dibujarConHitbox();
        botonDerecha.dibujarConHitbox();
        renderer.setView(camera);
        pantalla.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        pantalla.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    public void dispose() {
        jugador.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        pantalla.dispose();
    }

    public TiledMap getMap() {
        return map;
    }

}
```

But it seems that it doesn't recognize the touch on the screen or just by clicking it with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I found the solution. It seems that it wasn't enough to setBounds only on the class Botones, but also it is needed in the map where I'm implementing them. setBounds on the map, and everything's fine!